# Using Python mock to spy on calls to an existing object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the Python mock module for tests. I would like to replace an active object with a mock, and automatically have all calls made to the mock object forwarded to the original object. I think this is called a "Spy" in standard testing terminology. At the moment I'm doing inside a test:

```
# Insert a mock replacement
orig_active_attr = server.active_attr
server.active_attr = mock.Mock()

# Set up side effects to 'proxy' to the original object
server.active_attr.meth1.side_effect = orig_active_attr.meth1
server.active_attr.meth2.side_effect = orig_active_attr.meth2

# Call the method being tested
server.method_being_tested()

# Assert stuff on the mock.
server.active_attr.meth2.assert_called_once()
```

It would be nice if all method calls on the mock could be forwarded to the live object automatically without the boilerplate.

Comment: > It would be nice if all method calls on the mock could be forwarded to the live object automatically without the boilerplate. ----

no it wouldn't. a mock would not be a mock if it's _actually_ performing the behavior you want to mock.

Comment: Semantics I guess, what I'm looking for here is called a Spy, but the library that does it is called mock. Or at least that is how I understand it :)

Comment: See also [patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25608107/1048572), [Patch/Mock class method but still call original method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55898808/1048572) and [How to mock in python and still allow the actual code of mocked function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36717312/1048572)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled across the solution:

```
import mock

class A(object):
    def meth(self, a):
        return a
a = A()
ma = mock.Mock(wraps=a)
```

Seems to work okay for functions, methods and properties, but not for class or instance attributes.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class).

Answer (score 34):

You can use `patch.object(wraps=obj_instance)` as suggested in [Spying on instance methods with Python's mock module](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/spying-with-python-mocks/).

For example:

```
from mock import patch

class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x, y):
        return x + y + 1

def test_bar():
    foo = Foo()
    with patch.object(foo, 'bar', wraps=foo.bar) as wrapped_foo:
        foo.bar(1, 2)
        wrapped_foo.assert_called_with(1, 2)
```

Comment: `wraps` was added with Python 3.5. This should be the preferred solution now IMO.

Answer (score 4):

If you use pytest, the pytest-mock package has a convenient [spy](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#spy) object.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, v):
        return v * 2

def test_spy_method(mocker):
    foo = Foo()
    spy = mocker.spy(foo, 'bar')
    assert foo.bar(21) == 42

    spy.assert_called_once_with(21)
    assert spy.spy_return == 42
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to mock only `datetime.date.today()`, forwarding the rest of `datetime` calls to the `datetime` module:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase

import foo_module

class FooTest(TestCase):
  
    @mock.patch(f'{foo_module.__name__}.datetime', wraps=foo_module.datetime)
    def test_something(self, mock_datetime):
        # mock only datetime.date.today()
        mock_datetime.date.today.return_value = datetime.date(2019, 3, 15)
        # other calls to datetime functions will be forwarded to original datetime
```

`foo_module` imports `datetime` and uses many other `datetime` functions besides `date.today`.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer this Question about _spying_ (as opposed to what I think is just mocking in this answer).

Comment: This answers the question/problem statement in the description: _It would be nice if all method calls on the mock could be forwarded to the live object automatically without the boilerplate._

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple function to iterate through all the method and configure your mock

```
def spy_mock(instance):
    members = inspect.getmembers(instance, inspect.ismethod)
    attrs = {'%s.side_effect' % k:v for k,v in members}
    return mock.Mock(**attrs)
```

Usage would be

```
import inspect
from unittest import mock

class ActiveAttr:

    def meth2(self):
        print("Meth2 called")

class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.active_attr = ActiveAttr()

    def method_being_tested(self):
        self.active_attr.meth2()


def spy_mock(instance):
    members = inspect.getmembers(instance, inspect.ismethod)
    attrs = {'%s.side_effect' % k:v for k,v in members}
    return mock.Mock(**attrs)

server = Server()
server.active_attr = spy_mock(server.active_attr)

server.method_being_tested()

server.active_attr.meth2.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: It isn't clear how to use these modified methods that you're spying on. Could you show an example?

Comment: I think this doesn't answer this Question about _spying_ (as opposed to what I think is just mocking in this answer).

Comment: Been a long time since I answered this and @NeilenMarais answer is better. I still went ahead and updated the answer to show how it would use. It is indeed a spy that fulfills that answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Extending upon the [pattern from Wes McKinney](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/spying-with-python-mocks/) (via Wilfred Hughes Answer), here is **how to spy on a method/member of an object, where object is imported into module under test**.

**Note this solution is Python 2.x compliant!**

*module under test*:

```
import object

def function_in_module_under_test():
  object.method_from_imported_object()
```

*testing spied assertion on method_from_imported_object*:

```
from unittest import mock

import module_under_test    

def test_method(self):
  with mock.patch.object(
    module_under_test.object,
    "method_from_imported_object", 
    module_under_test.object.method_from_imported_object,
  ) as spy_method_from_imported_object:

    # Demonstrate that subsequent spy asserts here, can be trusted
    spy_method_from_imported_object.assert_not_called()
    
    # now Test
    module_under_test.function_in_module_under_test()
    spy_method_from_imported_object.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: awesome! I'm stuck with Python 2 so can't really use `wraps=bla` :-|

Comment: To test internal methods, I mocked the class first, then called `method_mocks` to find the absolute path.  Then I used `patch.object` to mock the object directly.  I had to use it with 2 args, b/c the third arg (new) points to the actual object I want to call, but it doesn't work with .assert* b/c it is not mock object.  Not sure if this was changed in later versions?