# Python Mocks: How to spy on instance methods that are created in runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to spy on a **class object** and see if **class instance method** is called with right parameters.

I can't use `Mock(wraps=obj_instance)` because the flow I trigger creates its own object instance.

I tried to use `Mock(spec=obj_class)` as seen in below, but it doesnt work.

Any ideas on how to spy on instance methods *without* creating the instance beforehand?

```py
from mock import Mock
import unittest


class CreditAPI:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs['user']

    def add_credit(self, amount):
        print("adding amount %s to user %s" % (amount, self.user))


def consume_credit():
    credit_api = CreditAPI(user="Ali")
    credit_api.add_credit(50)



class ConsumeCreditTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_consume_credit(self):
        m_credit_api = Mock(spec=CreditAPI)
        consume_credit()
        m_credit_api.__init__.assert_called_with(user="Ali")  # doesnt work
        m_credit_api.add_credit.assert_called_with(50)  # doesnt work


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What you're seeing is that consume_credit isn't very testable. You'd need to patch out the real CreditAPI at the module level with the current design.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe, I indeed patched creditAPI methods and it looks like I got it working half way. Posted my efforts below.

Answer (score 0):

With @jonrsharpe's help I managed to get it working by using `spec` like this:

```py
class ConsumeCreditTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_consume_credit(self):
        with patch('__main__.CreditAPI', spec=CreditAPI) as m_credit_api:
           consume_credit()
           m_credit_api.assert_called_with(user="Ali")
           m_credit_api().add_credit.assert_called_with(50)
```

Comment: You need to replace the whole thing, not patch bits of it: `with patch('__main__.CreditAPI', spec=CreditAPI) as m_credit_api:`. Note that your assertions would be `m_credit_api.assert_called_with` (*not* `__init__`) and `m_credit_api().add_credit.assert_called_with` or `m_credit_api.return_value.add_credit.assert_called_with` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch.

Comment: thank you a ton @jonrsharpe I managed to get it working your way. editing my answer :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe if would you like to post this as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as approved :)

Comment: If you're using that second one successfully I would suggest editing out the first part and accepting your own answer! Note that per https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop if you're using `.start()` *"you must ensure that the patching is “undone” by calling `stop`"*, which is why the context manager is encouraged.

Comment: edited out :) You're right about the start-stop thing. In my real-life case, the `act` part does not take place in the test code itself (I have dedicated routines for `arrange` and `assert`), so I can't use context manager there. But FWIW I edited my answer with CM as it better fits into the mock example here.

Comment: hello again @jonrsharpe, sorry for bothering over and over. Looks like the example above do not work: `add_credit` method seems indeed mocked instead of performing original functionality. ideas?

Comment: *"seems indeed mocked instead of performing original functionality"* - why did you expect otherwise? If you want the original functionality, *don't mock it*.

Comment: is it possible to `spy` using unittest, i.e. watch what argument are passed while preserving original functionality?

Comment: the `spy_decorator` wrapper (which I edited out yesterday) was indeed doing that. was kinda hoping I could perform that in a more elegant way.

Comment: spy_decorator ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427397/spying-on-class-instantiation-and-methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215323/discussion-between-ali-yilmaz-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: You can set up a mock that `wraps` the real thing, that's covered in the docs. However! Calling through is a bit of a test/design smell.

Comment: I tested `wraps`, but looks like it only works with instances. I have to pass an instance to `wraps` for it to work. In my case, instance is created at runtime, I don't have it beforehand. That was the actual question.

Comment: But you can create an identical instance - you're already asserting that the `CreditAPI` is instantiated with `"Ali"`, so you can wrap `CreditAPI("Ali")`. And this shows the problem with trying to test at this layer (and not inverting the dependency); they're coupled. The immediate problem seemed to be one of not actually replacing the thing you're trying to mock, but it seems like this is an XY problem with deeper roots - without concrete context, it's not really answerable.

Answer (score 0):

**Goal** - How to spy on a class without any instance? 
**Answer** - This does not appear to be possible as discovered above.  However, what is possible is to only spy on a single method of the class using `path.object`.  This preserves all other original method calls, so only mocking one method of the class is required.

```
class ConsumeCreditTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_consume_credit(self):
        with patch.object(CreditAPI, 'add_credit') as add_credit:
            consume_credit()
            add_credit.assert_called_with(50)
```

For more updates, [follow this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765682/3862024).  This post suggests that it may be possible to redirect back to original method, but it didn't work for me.  I will update if I find I missed something.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707979/3862024) helped me to better understand this scenario.