# Python mock: wrap instance method

Tags: python-2.7, python-mock

**What I would like:**
Ensure that all instances of `Foo` that are created inside the `with` statement have their `foo` instance method wrapped in a MagicMock via `wraps=Foo.foo`. The reason I want this is so that I can track `call_count` on the method `foo` for all instances of `Foo` that are created. Now that I say it like that it seems kind of impossible...

```
>>> from mock import patch
...
... class Foo(object):
...
...     def foo(self):
...         return "foo"
...
... with patch("__main__.Foo.foo", wraps=Foo.foo) as m:
...     foo = Foo()
...     print(foo.foo())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(foo.foo())
  File "/disk/software/lib/python27/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/disk/software/lib/python27/mock/mock.py", line 1132, in _mock_call
    return self._mock_wraps(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

**The problem**
The mocked `foo` method isn't bound to the `foo` instance created via `foo = Foo()` because it's wrapping the unbound method `Foo.foo`. Does anyone know how to ensure that the mocked method is bound to an instance?

**What I already know:**

```
>>> foo = Foo()
... with patch.object(foo, "foo", wraps=foo.foo) as m:
...     print(foo.foo())
"foo"
```

But this doesn't satisfy my constraint that the object must be instantiated inside the `patch` context.

Comment: Here is a method which works, but it uses try..finally and not the mock library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584656/max-recursion-depth-while-trying-to-mock-instance-method

Comment: I just spent a few hours trying to solve this same problem. Did you ever find something useful? @guettli's suggestion still relies on having a handle the the instance so it's not helpful if my tests isn't directly creating the instance.

Comment: @Colin Wrote out a relatively simple solution below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with my proposed and incorrect solution above

```
with patch("__main__.Foo.foo", wraps=Foo.foo) as m:
    ...
```

is that the `foo` method on `Foo` is mocked such that it wraps the unbound method `Foo.foo`, which naturally doesn't work, because the unbound method `Foo.foo` has no idea which instance it's attached to when called later on.

The simplest solution I could think of

```
from mock import patch, MagicMock

class Foo:

    def foo(self):
        return "foo"

class MockFoo(Foo):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Every instance of MockFoo will now have its `foo` method 
        # wrapped in a MagicMock
        self.foo = MagicMock(wraps=self.foo)

with patch("__main__.Foo", MockFoo) as m:
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.foo())
    assert foo.foo.call_count == 1
```

Comment: I've moved on from this problem, but this solution is very intriguing! I will give this a shot! Thanks for the idea @Filip Kilibarda!

Comment: You still need the instance. How is this different from the OP code?

Comment: @nitely Yeah you still need the instance to check the `call_count`, but you don't need the instance in order to apply the patch. This is useful in cases where a class is instantiated deep within the code under test and the instance is returned to the test code. When returned to the test code, the test can check the `call_count` of that particular instance. If you want to track the total sum `call_count` of all instances in the patch block without access to the instances themselves, then this is not the solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is so nasty with Python mocks so that I ended up building a custom patch implementation (extend with other features if required).

```
import contextlib

class Patcher:
    UNCHANGED_RET = object()

    def __init__(self):
        self.call_count = 0
        self.return_value = Patcher.UNCHANGED_RET


@contextlib.contextmanager
def patch(klass, method_name):
    patcher = Patcher()
    orig_method = getattr(klass, method_name)

    def new_method(myself, *args, **kwargs):
        patcher.call_count += 1
        orig_return_value = orig_method(myself, *args, **kwargs)

        if patcher.return_value != Patcher.UNCHANGED_RET:
            return patcher.return_value

        return orig_return_value

    setattr(klass, method_name, new_method)
    yield patcher
    setattr(klass, method_name, orig_method)
```

Use as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def f(self):
        return 42


x = MyClass()
with patch(MyClass, 'f') as f_patcher:
    y = MyClass()  # inside or outside -- does not matter
    assert x.f() == 42
    assert f_patcher.call_count == 1
    f_patcher.return_value = 7
    assert y.f() == 7
    assert f_patcher.call_count == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on Apport, I ran into the exact same question. I experimented with multiple approaches and came up with this solution, which is the most elegant and readable one:

```py
# Copyright (C) 2022, Benjamin Drung <bdrung@posteo.de>
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
# WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
# ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
# WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
# ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
# OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

import contextlib
import typing
import unittest.mock

@contextlib.contextmanager
def wrap_object(
    target: object, attribute: str
) -> typing.Generator[unittest.mock.MagicMock, None, None]:
    """Wrap the named member on an object with a mock object.

    wrap_object() can be used as a context manager. Inside the
    body of the with statement, the attribute of the target is
    wrapped with a :class:`unittest.mock.MagicMock` object. When
    the with statement exits the patch is undone.

    The instance argument 'self' of the wrapped attribute is
    intentionally not logged in the MagicMock call. Therefore
    wrap_object() can be used to check all calls to the object,
    but not differentiate between different instances.
    """
    mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
    real_attribute = getattr(target, attribute)

    def mocked_attribute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mock.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return real_attribute(self, *args, **kwargs)

    with unittest.mock.patch.object(target, attribute, mocked_attribute):
        yield mock
```

Unittest for `wrap_object`:

```py
class Multiply:
    """Test class for wrap_object test cases."""

    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self.multiplier = multiplier

    def multiply(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x * self.multiplier


class TestWrapObject(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_wrap_object_with_statement(self):
        with wrap_object(Multiply, "__init__") as mock:
            m = Multiply(7)
            self.assertEqual(m.multiply(6), 42)
        mock.assert_called_once_with(7)
```

Then you can use following code in your initial example:

```
>>> with wrap_object(Foo, "foo") as m:
...     foo = Foo()
...     print(foo.foo())
... 
foo
>>> m.assert_called_once_with()
>>> m.call_count
1
>>>
```