# Max recursion depth while trying to mock instance method

Tags: python, recursion, mocking

I want to mock an instance method. First I want to modify the arguments and then I want to call the original method.

I tried this:

```
import mock

class Foo(object):
    def my_method(data):
        print(data)

def wrapped_method(data):
    return Foo.my_method(data.replace('x', 'o'))

with mock.patch.object(Foo, 'my_method', wraps=wrapped_method):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.my_method('axe')  # should print "aoe"
```

But I get this exception:

```
/home/foo/bin/python /home/foo/src/wrap-instance-method.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/src/wrap-instance-method.py", line 15, in <module>
    foo.my_method('axe')  # should print "aoe"
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1024, in _mock_call
    return self._mock_wraps(*args, **kwargs)
.....
    return self._mock_wraps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/src/wrap-instance-method.py", line 10, in wrapped_method
    return Foo.my_method(data.replace('x', 'o'))
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 960, in _mock_call
    self.called = True
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I call the original method which was wrapped without recursion exception?

Comment: Could you please tell me why you down-vote this question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You replaced the `Foo.my_method` with a method that calls `Foo.my_method`, so yes, you'll get an infinite recursion.

If you *must* have the original method, you need to store it *before* you patch it:

```
def mock_method_factory(original):
    def wrapped_method(data):
        return original(data.replace('x', 'o'))
    return wrapped_method

with mock.patch.object(Foo, 'my_method', wraps=mock_method_factory(Foo.my_method)):
    # ...
```

However, `wraps` does not handle *binding*; `original` is an unbound function and `wrapped_method` won't be passed in `self`.

The `mock` library is perhaps not the best choice here. What you are essentially doing is apply a temporary decorator. Either subclass `Foo` or apply the decorator manually to `Foo.my_method`:

```
def mock_method_factory(original):
    def wrapped_method(self, data):
        return original(self, data.replace('x', 'o'))
    return wrapped_method

class MockedFoo(Foo):
    my_method = mock_method_factory(Foo.my_method)

foo = MockedFoo()
foo.my_method('axe')  # should print "aoe"
```

or

```
def mock_method_factory(original):
    def wrapped_method(self, data):
        return original(self, data.replace('x', 'o'))
    return wrapped_method

original = Foo.my_method
try:
    Foo.my_method = mock_method_factory(original)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.my_method('axe')  # should print "aoe"
finally:
    Foo.my_method = original
```

Comment: I added "return wrappend_method" since I think it is needed. Now I get "TypeError: unbound method my_method() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got str instance instead)"

Comment: @guettli: ah, yes, the replacement callable is not a method, so it won't be bound and no `self` is passed in.

Comment: Yes, not `self` is passed in. Sad. Is there an other way? I just want to do some kind of overwrite an instance method (comparable to inheritance and calling the parent method in the child method).

Comment: @guettli: added other ways that don't use `unittest.mock`.

Comment: Yes, the second solution (try..except (without mock)) works. I just need to add "self" here: `def wrapped_method(self, data)`

Comment: @guettli: yes, of course. By the way, you have the same problem in your question; the original `Foo.my_method` definition doesn't accept `self`.

Comment: You are right. But if I would add the argument "self" in the question, I would get "TypeError: wrappend_method() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)".... Strange, that it is not possbile with the mock library. But in this case I am happy with try...finally. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Tried with Martijn's solution, but had the self problem. Solved by the following:

```
real_constructor = CLASS_NAME.__init__
def mock_constructor(self, **args):
    return real_constructor.(self=self, **args)

with mock.patch.object(Foo, '__init__', side_effect=mock_constructor):
    ...
```