# Python, mocking and wrapping methods without instantating objects

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock a method of a class and use `wraps`, so that it is actually called, but I can inspect the arguments passed to it. I have seen at several places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608107/python-mock-patching-a-method-without-obstructing-implementation) for example) that the usual way to do that is as follows (adapted to show my point):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class Potato(object):
    def foo(self, n):
        return self.bar(n)

    def bar(self, n):
        return n + 2


class PotatoTest(TestCase):
    spud = Potato()

    @patch.object(Potato, 'foo', wraps=spud.foo)
    def test_something(self, mock):
        forty_two = self.spud.foo(n=40)
        mock.assert_called_once_with(n=40)
        self.assertEqual(forty_two, 42)
```

However, this instantiates the class `Potato`, in order to bind the mock to the instance method `spud.foo`.

What I need is to mock the method `foo` in  *all instances of `Potato`*, and wrap them around the original methods. I.e, I need the following:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class Potato(object):
    def foo(self, n):
        return self.bar(n)

    def bar(self, n):
        return n + 2


class PotatoTest(TestCase):
    @patch.object(Potato, 'foo', wraps=Potato.foo)
    def test_something(self, mock):
        self.spud = Potato()
        forty_two = self.spud.foo(n=40)
        mock.assert_called_once_with(n=40)
        self.assertEqual(forty_two, 42)
```

This of course doesn't work. I get the error:

```
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

It works however if `wraps` is not used, so the problem is not in the mock itself, but in the way it calls the wrapped function. For example, this works (but of course I had to "fake" the returned value, because now `Potato.foo` is never actually run):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class Potato(object):
    def foo(self, n):
        return self.bar(n)

    def bar(self, n):
        return n + 2


class PotatoTest(TestCase):
    @patch.object(Potato, 'foo', return_value=42)#, wraps=Potato.foo)
    def test_something(self, mock):
        self.spud = Potato()
        forty_two = self.spud.foo(n=40)
        mock.assert_called_once_with(n=40)
        self.assertEqual(forty_two, 42)
```

This works, but it does not run the original function, which I need to run because the return value is used elsewhere (and I cannot fake it from the test).

Can it be done?

**Note** The actual reason behind my needs is that I'm testing a rest api with webtest. From the tests I perform some wsgi requests to some paths, and my framework instantiates some classes and uses their methods to fulfill the request. I want to capture the parameters sent to those methods to do some `asserts` about them in my tests.

Comment: I saw this code recently. https://github.com/keleshev/value/blob/master/value.py involving `from inspect import getargspec`and `__new__` - not sure if that can be adapted to your needs. I'm pretty new to Python and haven't used patch... I believe this would allow you to inspect arguments

Comment: @JGFMK Thank you, but that seems unrelated. Apparently the code you linked is for inspecting the list of parameters of a function, even whitout calling it, but what I need is to capture the values of the actual arguments when the function is called.

Comment: How about this one? https://bitbucket.org/jsbueno/metapython/src/f48d6bd388fd/aspect.py?fileviewer=file-view-default - Got this by Googling AOP (Aspect Orientated Programming) in Python

Comment: What if you wrap `foo` in a function and pass it function to `wraps`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python mock - patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608107/python-mock-patching-a-method-without-obstructing-implementation)

Answer (score 6):

In short, you can't do this using `Mock` instances alone.

`patch.object` creates `Mock`'s for the specified instance (Potato), i.e. it replaces `Potato.foo` with a single Mock the moment it is called. Therefore, there is no way to pass instances to the `Mock` as the mock is created before any instances are. To my knowledge getting instance information to the `Mock` at runtime is also very difficult.

To illustrate:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class MyMock(MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(MyMock, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        print('Created Mock instance a={}, kw={}'.format(a,kw))

with patch.object(Potato, 'foo', new_callable=MyMock, wrap=Potato.foo):
    print('no instances created')
    spud = Potato()
    print('instance created')
```

The output is:

```
Created Mock instance a=(), kw={'name': 'foo', 'wrap': <function Potato.foo at 0x7f5d9bfddea0>}
no instances created
instance created
```

I would suggest monkey-patching your class in order to add the `Mock` to the correct location.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class PotatoTest(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):

        old_foo = Potato.foo
        try:
            mock = MagicMock(wraps=Potato.foo, return_value=42)
            Potato.foo = lambda *a,**kw: mock(*a, **kw)

            self.spud = Potato()
            forty_two = self.spud.foo(n=40)
            mock.assert_called_once_with(self.spud, n=40) # Now needs self instance
            self.assertEqual(forty_two, 42)
        finally:
            Potato.foo = old_foo
```

Note that you using `called_with` is problematic as you are calling your functions with an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks identical to [python mock - patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608107) to me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72446739/9230828 implements what you want (except that it uses a with statement instead of a decorator). `wrap_object.py`:

```
# Copyright (C) 2022, Benjamin Drung <bdrung@posteo.de>
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
# WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
# ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
# WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
# ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
# OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

import contextlib
import typing
import unittest.mock

@contextlib.contextmanager
def wrap_object(
    target: object, attribute: str
) -> typing.Generator[unittest.mock.MagicMock, None, None]:
    """Wrap the named member on an object with a mock object.

    wrap_object() can be used as a context manager. Inside the
    body of the with statement, the attribute of the target is
    wrapped with a :class:`unittest.mock.MagicMock` object. When
    the with statement exits the patch is undone.

    The instance argument 'self' of the wrapped attribute is
    intentionally not logged in the MagicMock call. Therefore
    wrap_object() can be used to check all calls to the object,
    but not differentiate between different instances.
    """
    mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
    real_attribute = getattr(target, attribute)

    def mocked_attribute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mock.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return real_attribute(self, *args, **kwargs)

    with unittest.mock.patch.object(target, attribute, mocked_attribute):
        yield mock
```

Then you can write following unit test:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from wrap_object import wrap_object


class Potato:
    def foo(self, n):
        return self.bar(n)

    def bar(self, n):
        return n + 2


class PotatoTest(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        with wrap_object(Potato, 'foo') as mock:
            self.spud = Potato()
            forty_two = self.spud.foo(n=40)
        mock.assert_called_once_with(n=40)
        self.assertEqual(forty_two, 42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you control creation of `Potato` instances, or at least have access to these instances after creating them? You should, else you'd not be able to check particular arg lists. 
If so, you can wrap methods of individual instances using

```
spud = dig_out_a_potato()
with mock.patch.object(spud, "foo", wraps=spud.foo) as mock_spud:
  # do your thing.
  mock_spud.assert_called...
```