# Spying on class instantiation and methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I want to be able to see how classes are instantiated and I want to see how  how methods of that class are used. I can accomplish the first goal, but, the code below demonstrates how I can't spy on the method calls. The final assert fails.

```
import mock

class A:
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        print("constructor")

    def f(self, some_var):
        print(some_var)

p = mock.patch('__main__.A', wraps=A)
m = p.start()
A = m
a = A('something')
a.f('my_arg')
assert mock.call('something') in m.mock_calls
assert m.method_calls  # This fails, call to f is not tracked
```

If I use autospec=True I can see the method calls, but then the actual method isn't called. I want the actual code to run, I just want to spy on it.

I can't do something like http://wesmckinney.com/blog/spying-with-python-mocks/ because I don't have an instance of the class.

Comment: Not related, but you don't need `A = m`; the patch already causes `A` to refer to the mock, not the original class.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a straightforward way to accomplish this. `wrap` only handles calls to functions (or other callable). The *call* to the mocked `A` results in a call to the real `A`, but the return value simply isn't a mock; it's a regular instance of the original class.

Answer (score 4):

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599695/9816369 has a pretty solid solution. From that, I can do this:

```
import mock


def spy_decorator(method_to_decorate):
    m = mock.MagicMock()
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        m(*args, **kwargs)
        return method_to_decorate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.mock = m
    return wrapper


class A:
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        print("constructor")

    def f(self, some_var):
        print(some_var)


construct_spy = spy_decorator(A.__init__)
f_spy = spy_decorator(A.f)
p_construct = mock.patch('__main__.A.__init__', construct_spy)
p_f = mock.patch('__main__.A.f', f_spy)

m_construct = p_construct.start()
m_f = p_f.start()

a = A("hi")
a.f("car")

m_construct.mock.assert_called_once_with("hi")
m_f.mock.assert_called_once_with("car")
```

It could be a bit nicer, but this is pretty solid. I should also mention that there is https://github.com/beanbaginc/kgb but I didn't want to modify the requirements file I'm working with.