# How to unit test instance variables initialized outside __init__ method

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class that initializes an instance variable in a method other than `__init__`. That instance variable is further referred to in the `__init__` method.

In the code below, `ProductionClass` is the class I am testing. In `ProductionClass`, `__init__` makes a call to method `a_method`. Method `a_method` initializes an instance variable `inst_var_2`. `inst_var_2` is used by `__init__` to set another instance variable `inst_var_3`.

```
class LibraryClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attrib = "some_attrib_value"

class ProductionClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg_one):
        self.inst_var_1 = arg_one
        self.a_method()
        self.inst_var_3 = self.inst_var_2.some_attrib

    def a_method(self):
        self.inst_var_2 = LibraryClass()


import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class ProdTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(ProductionClass, 'a_method')
    def test_init_method(self, mock_method):

        instance = ProductionClass(1234)
        self.assertEqual(1234, instance.inst_var_1)
        mock_method.assert_called_once_with()
```

I am trying to unit test the `__init__` method of `ProductionClass` and I am unable to create an instance of the `ProductionClass`, due to missing instance variable `inst_var_2`. Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  ...

  File "/...     production_class.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.inst_var_3 = self.inst_var_2.some_attrib
AttributeError: 'ProductionClass' object has no attribute 'inst_var_2'
```

My question, is it possible to unit test the `__init__` method while I am mocking the `a_method`. I want to mock `a_method` because I don't want the method to instantiate `LibraryClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is essentially the same as: [python mock - patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25608107/674039).

Since you mocked out `a_method`, it doesn't get to set the `self.inst_var_2`.  Therefore the `__init__` can not succeed.  You will have to account for this in the test, however, you can still assert that the mock was called:

```
@patch.object(ProductionClass, 'a_method')
def test_init_method(self, mock_method):
    with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
        ProductionClass(1234):
    mock_method.assert_called_once_with()
```

> I want to mock `a_method` because I don't want the method to instantiate `LibraryClass`.

It will be better to patch out `your_module.LibraryClass`, not `a_method`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a way to call  `assert_called_once_with` even if instantiation of `ProductionClass` fails. Also your suggestion that I mock out `LibraryClass` instead of `a_method` is very helpful. Sometimes I tend to get stuck in taking a "pure" approach when I am mocking out all method calls form the method I am calling...

Comment: The link to your question is very helpful too. I will try to apply some of the techniques outlined there in my tests.