# Attempt to patch a member function yields error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I would like to assert from a UT, `TestRunner.test_run` that some deeply nested function `Prompt.run_cmd` is called with the string argument `"unique cmd"`. My setup besically resembles the following:

```
# Module application/engine/prompt.py
class Prompt:
    def run_cmd(self, input):
        pass
        
# Module: application/scheduler/runner.py   
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prompt = application.engine.prompt.Prompt()

    def run(self):
        self.prompt.run_cmd("unique cmd")
        
        
# Module tests/application/scheduler/runner_test.py
class TestRunner(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    def test_run(self):
        # calls Runner.run
        # Objective assert that Prompt.run is called with the argument "unique cmd"
        # Current attempt below:
        with mock.patch(application.engine.prompt, "run_cmd") as mock_run_cmd:
           pass
```

Unfortunately my attempts to mock the `Prompt.run_cmd` fail with the error message

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'object'`

Comment: `mock.patch()` takes a string argument, not an object. Maybe you mean `mock.patch.object()`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks. `mock.patch()` is what I meant to use. What I'm trying to do is to assert that the argument "unique_cmd" is passed to `Prompt.run_cmd()`. The slight problem is that `Prompt.run_cmd()` is called often by other functions and so it cannot be mocked away. I'd like to swap `Prompt.run_cmd()` with a function `Bar.foo()` that (1) forwards all invocations to `Prompt.run_cmd()` and (2) can assert whether "unique_cmd" was passed to `Prompt.run_cmd()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to patch a concrete instance, you could easily do this using `mock.patch.object` and `wraps` (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608107/python-mock-patching-a-method-without-obstructing-implementation).

If you want to patch your function for *all* instances instead, you indeed have to use `mock.patch`. In this case you could only mock the class itself, as mocking the method would not work (because it is used on instances, not classes), so you cannot use `wraps` here (at least I don't know a way to do this).

What you could do instead is derive your own class from `Prompt` and overwrite the method to collect the calls yourself. You could then patch `Prompt` by your own implementation. Here is a simple example:

```py
class MyPrompt(Prompt):
    calls = []

    def run_cmd(self, input):
        super().run_cmd(input)
        # we just add a string in the call list - this could be more sophisticated
        self.__class__.calls.append(input)

class TestRunner(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_run(self):
        with mock.patch("application.engine.prompt.Prompt", MyPrompt) as mock_prompt:
            runner = Runner()
            runner.run()
            self.assertEqual(["unique cmd"], mock_prompt.calls)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `MyPrompt` in `with mock.patch("application.engine.prompt.Prompt", MyPrompt) as mock_prompt:` be  `MyPrompt()`

Comment: No, because you are patching the class, not an instance.