# unittest.mock.patch - "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when mocking a function with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, patch

I am trying to write some tests for my flask app using `pytest`. I am mocking a function with `unittest.mock.patch`. I seem to be having issues with the mocked function not being callable when using the `@patch` decorator.

Instead of showing my flask code, I have a simplified, contrived example below to demonstrate the issue I am having.

The example directory:

```
|-- outer.py
|-- util.py
|-- test_example.py
```

util.py:

```
import os

def getUsername():
    user = os.getenv('username')   
    return(user)
```

outer.py:

```
from util import getUsername

def add_user_age():
    age = 111
    user = getUsername()
    return(f"{age}:{user}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = add_user_age()
    print(x)
```

test_example.py:

```
from outer import add_user_age
from unittest.mock import patch 

@patch("outer.getUsername","JohnDoe")
def test_example():
    s = add_user_age()
    assert s == "111:JohnDoe"
```

Output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: C:\flask\pytest_concept, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.3.1, openfiles-0.3.1, doctestplus-0.2.0, arraydiff-0.3
collected 1 item

test_example.py F                                                        [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_example _________________________________

    @patch("outer.getUsername","JohnDoe")
    def test_example():
>       s = add_user_age()

test_example.py:6:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def add_user_age():
        age = 111
>       user = getUsername()
E       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

outer.py:5: TypeError
========================== 1 failed in 0.06 seconds ===========================
```

The idea is that I am wanting to mock the `getUsername` function that is used in `combine_age111_and_username`. When I mock it though, it says that the 'str' object is not callable; however, if I make the change as such in `add_user_age`:

outer.py (changed):

```
from util import getUsername

def add_user_age():
    #...
    user = getUsername # The change is right here, notice that I am not calling it
    #...
```

The tests will pass as expected:

```
C:\flask\pytest_concept>python -m pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: C:\flask\pytest_concept, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.3.1, openfiles-0.3.1, doctestplus-0.2.0, arraydiff-0.3
collected 1 item

test_example.py .                                                        [100%]

========================== 1 passed in 0.04 seconds ===========================

C:\flask\pytest_concept>
```

However, that change will make `add_user_age` return the incorrect result if it is ran outside of pytest, as it will return a function object instead of the current logged on user. I want to be able to use the patch decorator without having to change the behaviour of `add_user_age()` in `outer.py`.

Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's because you're patching a whole name to be a thing you said. Basically doing `getUsername="JohnDoe"`. I believe you can use `@path("my_function", return_value="this will be returned")` (`patch` docs say that kwargs will be given to resulting Mock and Mock accepts `return_value` keyword)

Comment: @h4z3: I end up getting `TypeError: test_example() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` if I try adding the `return_value` param to the patch decorator. Full error is here: https://pastebin.com/NPYJ7Fyx .

Comment: Oh, I had to add the return_value to the test_function itself, as in `def test_example(return_value)` in addition to what you suggested. That's frustrating to figure out. I think I have my answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could patch `os.getenv` itself:

```
from outer import add_user_age
import os
import contextlib
from unittest import mock


@contextlib.contextmanager
def fakeGetEnv(*args):
    with mock.patch.object(
        os, 'getenv', mock.Mock(wraps=os.getenv)
    ) as patched:
        patched.return_value = args[0]
        yield


def test_example():
    expectedUser = 'JohnDoe'
    with fakeGetEnv(expectedUser):
        s = add_user_age()
        assert s == f"111:{expectedUser}"
```

Comment: so `FakeGetEnv` will always return the first argument you pass in, which would be 'JohnDoe' in this case? I'm just trying to understand what the purpose of the `wraps` parameter is in `Mock()`. Your test case passes with the absence of it when I run pytest.

Comment: Oh. I'm guessing it has something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869141/using-python-mock-to-spy-on-calls-to-an-existing-object

Comment: Personally, I prefer to set expected result within the test not a decorator. If you use `wraps` with `return_value` the given return value is used instead of calling the function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock))